# Faster way to apply lambda function to Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have Pandas dataframe which is a (large number of times) repetition of a smaller dataframe, but only one column is not repeated. I want to apply a function that works on this non-repeated column and one of the repeating columns. But the whole procedure is slow and I need an alternative way that works faster. Here is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

repeating_times = 4
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*repeating_times,
                   "col2": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']*repeating_times,
                   "true": ['P', 'P', 'N', 'P', 'N']*repeating_times,
                   "pred": random.choices(["P", "N"], k=5*repeating_times)})

grps = df.groupby(by=["col1", "col2"])
true_pos = grps.apply(lambda gr: np.sum(gr[gr['pred'] == 'P']["true"] == 'P'))
true_pos
```

`true_pos` measures the true positive samples (where prediction and true values are of positive class) for all groups of (col1, col2).

**Update:**
A better way of doing that which makes it much faster is to use `agg` instead of apply the function.

```
repeating_times = 4
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]*repeating_times,
                   "col2": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']*repeating_times,
                   "true": ['P', 'P', 'N', 'P', 'N']*repeating_times,
                   "pred": random.choices(["P", "N"], k=5*repeating_times)})

df["true_pos"] = (df["true"]=="P") & (df["pred"]=="P")

true_pos = df.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).agg({"true_pos": "sum"})
```

Answer (score 1):

In these cases, you can approach from the other angle: first compute the inner conditions, i.e., both "true" and "pred" being "P", and then group *that* by the col_1 and col_2 & sum:

```py
>>> (df["true"].eq("P") & df["pred"].eq("P")).groupby([df["col1"], df["col2"]]).sum()

col1  col2
1     a       4
2     b       2
3     c       0
4     d       0
5     e       0
dtype: int64
```

---

here is the thing that's being grouped:

```py
>>> (df["true"].eq("P") & df["pred"].eq("P"))

0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5      True
6      True
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11     True
12    False
13    False
14    False
15     True
16    False
17    False
18    False
19    False
dtype: bool
```

Then the .groupby will look at where the unique col1 and col2 pairs correspond into this, and sum that for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer, but it still does not solve the problem with time. This is only a bit more efficient than mine. I need an approach that can significantly reduce the computation time.